# jenkins dsl job script: How to access environment variable, (which is injected via propertiesFile, ) in downstreamParameterized step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

my dsl job script in brief

```
job('test') {
  steps {
    shell('echo VERSION=$VERSION > version.txt\n' +
          'echo VERSION_SUFFIX=$VERSION_SUFFIX >> version.txt\n' + 
          'echo GROUP_ID=$GROUP_ID >> version.txt')

    // EnvInject Plugin 
    environmentVariables {
      propertiesFile('version.txt')
    }
  }

  publishers {
    postBuildScripts {
        steps {
            shell('echo ${VERSION}')
        }
        onlyIfBuildSucceeds(false)
        onlyIfBuildFails(false)
    }
    downstreamParameterized {
      trigger('next-job') {
        parameters {
          predefinedProp('relVersion', '${VERSION}')
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

I need $VERSION number to pass to the downstream job a parameter.

I  tried,  ${env.VERSION} and also tried many options, but i couldn't catch the VERSION . any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `shell('cat version.txt')` before `environmentVariables {}` block to print out the content of  `version.txt`.  I did a quick practice on my jenkins to create two simple jenkins jobs to simulate your case. They can work as expect. Then I run your Job DSL in http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/,  the DSL generate similar XML as my job's config.xml.  So I think your DSL is correct.  Maybe the generated version.txt is not correct.

Comment: after environmentVariables {},  i have `publishOverSsh { 
        server('apsbds01-ernam') {
           execCommand('cd '+playbookPath+'\n' + 
                        'echo "$VERSION"\n' + ...  `  so  version.txt is just fine in my opinion.

Comment: If so, another possibility is you inject environment values in `Build` stage,  but we refer the environment in `Post Action` stage. Those environment values' lifecycle in ending by the end of `Build` stage, not pass down to `Post Action` stage.  From my jenkins'  `Env Inject` plugin, its help document says the variable will pass down to `Post Action` stage,  I can't sure you used `Env Inject` version is support pass down or not.

Comment: So you can add a `Shell` in `Post Action` to print out the environment variable: `${VERSION}`.  If it work, means your Env Inject plugin pass down variables from Build to Post Action stage, and your job DSL should work.

Comment: I update your code to add `postBuildScripts` into `publishers` to print out the `${VERSION}`. Please give a try.

Comment: thanks, yes, variable passing down to post build, seems to be working. but struggle continues on reading relVersion before SCM step, as first 2 digits (x.y) is the brach name job(next-job) { parameters { stringParam ('branch', 'System.getProperty('relVersion')', 'my description') } scm { git { remote { url("ssh://git@bitbucket.rl.git") } branches('$branch') } } its not working, can you help on this ?

Comment: I give a code in my answer. I cann't run on my jenkins due to my jenkins script security limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `Prepare an environment for the run` which is executed before SCM.

Option `Prepare an environment for the run` is not belongs `pre-build/ build /post build`, but job `properties`.

There is no job DSL API supports to configure this option. But we can use [configure](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) block.

```
job('next-job') {

  configure { project -> 
    project / 'properties' << 'EnvInjectJobProperty' {

        info {
          loadFilesFromMaster false
          propertiesContent 'Branch=${relVersion}'
        }
        keepBuildVariables true
        keepJenkinsSystemVariables true
        overrideBuildParameters false
        on true
    }
  } // end of configure block

  scm { 
    git { 
      remote { 
        url("ssh://git@bitbucket.rl.git") 
      } 
        branches('${branch}') 
    } 
  } // end of scm

  steps {}
  publishers {}
}
```

Above job DSL can generate following xml as the content of seed job's config.xml

```
<project>
    <actions></actions>
    <description></description>
    <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
    <properties>
        <EnvInjectJobProperty>
            <info>
                <loadFilesFromMaster>false</loadFilesFromMaster>
                <propertiesContent>Branch=${relVersion}</propertiesContent>
            </info>
            <keepBuildVariables>true</keepBuildVariables>
            <keepJenkinsSystemVariables>true</keepJenkinsSystemVariables>
            <overrideBuildParameters>false</overrideBuildParameters>
            <on>true</on>
        </EnvInjectJobProperty>
    </properties>
    <canRoam>true</canRoam>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers></triggers>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders></builders>
    <publishers></publishers>
    <buildWrappers></buildWrappers>
    <scm class='hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM'>
        <userRemoteConfigs>
            <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
                <url>ssh://git@bitbucket.rl.git</url>
            </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        </userRemoteConfigs>
        <branches>
            <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
                <name>${branch}</name>
            </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        </branches>
        <configVersion>2</configVersion>
        <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
        <gitTool>Default</gitTool>
    </scm>
</project>
```

You can try jod DSL on http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ to check generated xml from it as expect or not.

Comment: thanks for inputs,  for both options, i see below   ERROR: (jobs-bitcket.groovy, line 357) No such property: env for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.DownstreamTriggerContext  .  am i missing something ?

Comment: `predefinedProp('relVersion', "$VERSION") `  ERROR: (jobs-bitcket.groovy, line 358) No such property: VERSION for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.DownstreamTriggerContext

Comment: ma be dsl version mismatch: couldn't use keepBuildVariables(true)
 javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepEnvironmentVariableContext.keepBuildVariables() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]

Comment: ` environmentVariables { propertiesFile('version.txt')}                downstreamParameterized {  trigger(jobName") {  parameters { currentBuild() }  } ` is working  for me , but still  i coudln't get  version in the next function 
            getBinding().getVariables()['VERSION']  prins as null , seems variables are not passed.

Comment: ERROR: (jobs-bitcket.groovy, line 628) No such property: currentBuild for class: jobs_by_bit.   even if its works, it doesn't help.  this script only creates the jobs.  But I need to read the relVersion when job build  executing..   I mean, reading the variable , should be part of build step , before SCM.

Comment: looking  options, "Prepare an environment for the run" build step,   Evaluated Groovy script , might be an option for me.

Comment: Yes,  "Prepare an environment for the run"  can inject environment before SCM, I tried almost a whole day, no luck to work out a DSL code block equivalent to that option.

Comment: all seems to be fine, but  still it prints origin/${relVersion}  on branch name.  may be for now. i would include all git commands in shell. that would do the work, until i find better solution. i appreciate your time and efforts, thanks yong.

Comment: Hi, noticed, i couldn't get any variable from previous job to node, even to shell scripts.  may be issue wih our environment.

Comment: Try add `triggerWithNoParameters(false)` behind `predefinedProp('relVersion', '${VERSION}')` in first job.  https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.downstreamParameterized-trigger-triggerWithNoParameters

Comment: yes, tried that also. its weird , not working only in my setup